# Monoprice MP10 Mini, can't get a decent print

Tags: z-axis, bed-leveling

**Update: if i press the button "Home" it will correctly posizionate the nozzle above the printing bed, with a gap wide enough to insert a sheet of paper between the nozzle and the surface.
But, and here's the strange thing, if i move the printing bed the z axis motor will rotate causing the nozzle to get too close to the surface, scratching it.**

I recently bought my first 3D printer, a Monoprice MP10 Mini. Unfortunately not a nice choice so far.

I calibrated the printer 3 times and after every print the Z axis seems to be completely off.

As a consequence, it scratched the printing bed many times. 
On top of that it seems I can't get a decent print anymore, I don't know how I can describe this problem, so just look at the pictures:

[image]

[image]

Comment: It looks as if your magnetic print surface is not flat anymore. Could also be a problem with the rollers of the non driven vertical axis.

Comment: Put a straight edge on your plate ... agreeing with @0scar ... it isn't flat.

Comment: I thought the same, but it's not just that, there's something wrong with the auto leveling too, I updated the original post. Even during auto leveling, the vertical motor is moving, causing the nozzle to get too close to the surface